# How do I fix ASP.NET Error CS0103

Tags: c#, asp.net

What causes the ASP.NET Error CS0103? I get that error saying that `Label01` can not be found in the current context` when I try to compile the project.

What is causing it?

Comment: Can you post code, it sounds like you are referencing a control named `Lable01` which doesn't exist. P.s. Do you mean `Label01`?

Comment: not exactly.... This error occurs while making a dll (I do need a dll for my project when I compile my code...) So, I when I compile any code using the (%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe) Then I get this error upon compilation....

Comment: You need to post the code for the class where the compiler error occurs.

Comment: Of course.... I not matters with code it just happens to compile any any any code consists of windows forms... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a control with that name in the page, and that it is included in the `.designer` file. If not, then add it or remove it as needed.

The designer sometimes gets out of sync with the page's markup. Alternatively, right-click on the page that's causing the error and select 'Convert to Web Application' to force a sync.

Comment: Yeah...! its a good idea to try but how to generate .designer file? I am using VS2005 I cannot find an open 'Convert to Web Application' anywhere

Comment: @Karthik, try deleting the designer file, then right click the ASPX file and do convert to web application. I remember having to do this constantly in VS2005!

Comment: Download a newer version of VS here: http://microsoft.com/express
It is no point using VS2005 nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Also try the following fix,

**Delete the .vs directory beside your solution, as it might have invalid data cached.**

[Source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168741/still-getting-thousands-of-cs0103-errors-from-inte.html?childToView=170336#comment-170336)